# Difference between React Render and Hydrate

Tags: reactjs

What is the different between React "hydrate" and "render" method? I have used both but i didnt see any difference in how they work. I understand that "hydrate" is using for SSR but i have tried using both for "SSR" content and they both work the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `render` and `hydrate` methods in React are used for similar purposes, but there is a subtle difference between them.

### render

The `render` method is primarily used for client-side rendering. It takes a React component and mounts it into a specified DOM element in the browser. This is done during the initial page load or when dynamically rendering new components in response to user interactions.

### hydrate

The `hydrate` method is also used for rendering React components into the DOM, but it is specifically designed for Server-Side Rendering (SSR) scenarios. It performs the same initial rendering as the `render` method but also attaches event listeners to the existing markup generated on the server.

When using SSR, the server generates the initial HTML markup for the React components. The `hydrate` method then takes this markup and attaches event listeners and performs event reconciliation to make the client-side behavior match the server-rendered markup. This allows the React application to take over the interactivity without re-rendering everything from scratch.

Note that these methods will be replaced : [render](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/render) will be replaced by [createRoot](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot) and [hydrate](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hydrate) will be replaced by [hydrateRoot](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot)